# Using a punch down tool with an Ethernet face plate

Tags: networking, ethernet, wiring

I recently purchased the tool that can be seen below and it was described as a wire cutter and punch down tool.

I can't figure how to use it as a punch down tool.

Does anyone have any idea how to use this to connect up an Ethernet faceplate?

[image: Punch Down Tool]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have punch-down faceplates:

[image: Punch-down RJ-45 jack]

I believe you use the tip of the tool to seat each wire into the appropriate slot and push it into place (but do not actually have any experience doing so).

Comment: Lay the wire across the slot (parallel) maintaining the twist as close to the inside as possible. The blade is positioned over the top of the wire parallel to the slot. The notch in the middle of the blade allows for clearance on the connector fork down inside the slot. Put the connector on a solid surface and push the blade straight down till it bottoms in the slot.  Trim off excess protruding to the outside. Quality Paladin 110 tools do the punchdown to proper pressure and waste trim in one pass.

Comment: I highly suggest using an impact punch-down tool in place of that one. With an impact tool you can be assured that the wire is sitting correctly and it also makes a much better cut. There are other brands beside Palidin that will suffice and be much cheaper, but the key is the word "impact".

Comment: The worst was a plastic punchdown tool that came with some cheapie jacks a friend of mine bought. They didn't even bother putting the metal insert in. He got through half a jack as he didn't understand the push in straight part.

Answer (score 2):

Darth is correct. Here is a simple [tutorial](http://www.datacomtools.com/catalog/how-to-use-a-punch-down-tool.htm).

[image]

Here's a [video](http://youtu.be/0gxNZoPcnP4) to show how to do it.